Chrome extension to change youtube video title leads to empty title on the next video when I click next
I'm working on youtube chrome extension to change the title of a Youtube video , but after changing and clicking next then, the video's title is empty and when I click next again the custom title I wrote is appended to the new video's title.
Here is the popup.js:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const tabId = await getCurrentTabId();

    // Load and set the auto-generate checkbox state
    chrome.storage.local.get('autoGenerateOnReload', (result) => {
        document.getElementById('autoSet').checked = result.autoGenerateOnReload || false;
    });

    // Listen for video changes
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
        if (message.type === 'VIDEO_CHANGED') {
            handleVideoChange(tabId);
        }
    });
});

document.getElementById('changeTitle').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const customTitle = document.getElementById('customTitle').value;
    if (customTitle) {
        const tabId = await getCurrentTabId();
        setTitleOnPage(tabId, customTitle);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ storedTitle: customTitle });
    }
});

document.getElementById('autoSet').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ autoGenerateOnReload: event.target.checked });
});

document.getElementById('generateAIButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const tabId = await getCurrentTabId();
    generateNewTitle(tabId);
});

async function handleVideoChange(tabId) {
    // Clear stored title on video change
    chrome.storage.local.remove('storedTitle');

    chrome.storage.local.get('autoGenerateOnReload', async (result) => {
        if (result.autoGenerateOnReload) {
            await generateNewTitle(tabId);
        } else {
            const originalTitle = await getOriginalTitle(tabId);
            setTitleOnPage(tabId, originalTitle);
        }
    });
}

async function setTitleOnPage(tabId, title) {
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId },
        func: (newTitle) => {
            const titleElement = document.querySelector('h1.style-scope.ytd-watch-metadata yt-formatted-string');
            if (titleElement) {
                titleElement.textContent = newTitle;
            }
        },
        args: [title]
    });
}

async function generateNewTitle(tabId) {
    const prompt = 'Generate a catchy YouTube title in French';
    const generateButton = document.getElementById('generateAIButton');
    generateButton.textContent = 'Loading...';
    generateButton.disabled = true;

    try {
        const newTitle = await generateUsingAI(prompt);
        if (newTitle && newTitle.trim()) {
            await setTitleOnPage(tabId, newTitle.trim());
            chrome.storage.local.set({ storedTitle: newTitle.trim() });
        } else {
            alert("Failed to generate a valid title. Please try again.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error generating title using AI:", error);
    } finally {
        generateButton.textContent = 'Generate Using AI';
        generateButton.disabled = false;
    }
}

async function generateUsingAI(prompt) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/openai/generate-title?prompt=' + encodeURIComponent(prompt));
        const newTitle = await response.text();
        return newTitle.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error generating title using AI:", error);
        return '';
    }
}

function getCurrentTabId() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            resolve(tabs[0].id);
        });
    });
}

async function getOriginalTitle(tabId) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId },
            func: () => {
                const titleElement = document.querySelector('h1.style-scope.ytd-watch-metadata yt-formatted-string');
                return titleElement ? titleElement.textContent : '';
            }
        }, (results) => {
            resolve(results[0].result || '');
        });
    });
}


and content.js:
// content.js

// Track the last known video ID
let lastVideoId = '';

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    const currentUrl = location.href;
    const videoId = new URL(currentUrl).searchParams.get('v');

    if (videoId && videoId !== lastVideoId) {
        lastVideoId = videoId;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'VIDEO_CHANGED', videoId });
    }
});

// Observe changes in the DOM
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });


Can anyone help me to know where I'm doing anything wrong?
I have tried many approaches including using a background.js , but nothing seems to work perfectly.

The popup runs only when it's shown, so indeed you need to split the code that listens to messages from the content script into a separate background script.

what will that help @woxxom? To make sure the title doesn't disappear I'm not sure!
